# What does self[] mean in a method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When reading a python program, I once find a function uses `self` in the following way.

```
class Auto(object):
   _biases_str = "biases{0}"

   def _b(self, n, suffix=""):
     name_b_out = self._biases_str.format(i + 1) + "_out"
     return `self[self._biases_str.format(n) + suffix]`
```

The line of `name_b_out = self._biases_str.format(i + 1) + "_out"`  looks usual to me, i.e., we always `self.` to define something. But I am not very clear about the usage of `self[self._biases_str.format(n) + suffix]`. In specifc, what does `self[]` mean here, or what does it do?

Comment: are the `\`backticks\`` supposed to be there too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything other than what `variable[something]` would mean. In Python `variable[something]` in an expression will just call `variable.__getitem__(something)`, and `self` is the name conventionally used for the current object, or the receiver, in Python, so `self[self._biases_str.format(n) + suffix]` would mean pretty much the same as `self.__getitem__(self._biases_str.format(n) + suffix)`

I guess there is a method `__getitem__` defined for that class as well.

Comment: [Subscriptions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscriptable#subscriptions)